# Backbone event not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Am trying to add and remove a class based on the link that is clicked using BackboneJS Events based on a tutorial I saw but am not sure why my code is not working.

If the link is clicked add the class "selected" to it and remove the class "selected" from any other link that may have had it.

I am not sure why the Event is not firing.  Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/EL8gM/

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        items: [
            {
                "name": "One",
                "id": 1           
            },
            {
                "name": "Two",
                "id": 2           
            },
            {
                 "name": "Three",
                 "id": 3           
            }
        ]
    }
});

var myModel = new Model();

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.js-container',

    initialize: function(options) {
        // Re-render when the model changes
        this.model.on('change:items', this.render, this);
    },

    template: _.template($('#list-template').html()),

    events: {
        "#items li a": "this.setSelectedItem"
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },

    setSelectedItem: function(event) {
        var selectedItem = $(event.currentTarget);
        console.log('selectedItem =', selectedItem)
        // Set all of the items to not have the selected class
        $('#items li a').removeClass('selected');
        selectedItem.addClass('selected');
        // Store a reference to what item was selected
        this.selectedItemId = selectedItem.data('id');
        return false;
    }
});

var myView = new View({model: myModel});
myView.render();
```

Here is my HTML

```
<script id="list-template" type="template">
    <ul id="items">
        <% for(i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { %>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-id="<%= items[i].id %>"><%= items[i].name %></a>
            </li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</script>

<div class="js-container"></div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question to include the fixed code because then people skimming the page can't "visually diff" what was borked in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
events: {
    "click #items li a": "setSelectedItem"
},
```

edit: there's another typo where you misspelled console

```
cosnole.log('selectedItem =', selectedItem)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the fiddle but that doesn't seem to work still.  Thanks for checking, I've been trying to learn backbone though it's been a slow process and am just trying to figure out events now.  I'll update the question with the new code and fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/EL8gM/

Comment: It works. In your new fiddle you changed this line:  
var selectedItem = $(event.currentTarget);

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry about that.